# to establish the connection with the some web page in python

Tags: python, linux, networking, ubuntu-10.04

I have to work on a project in which I have to establish the connection with the web page so that I can collect the xml dtd schema fragments from that page and apply my search algorithm on it which searches the keywords entered by the user.  I have already created the algorithm in python, but don't know how to establish the connection in python , since I'm new to it. Can anyone guide me at this?

Please Help

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Comment: As always, the python stdlib is your friend. Study it, there's even a special [section for internet protocols](http://docs.python.org/library/internet.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean just to fetch a web page, you can try like this:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.example.com/index.html'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
#now you can get the data by response.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend spawning sockets etc. for HTTP while there are libs like urllib2 as mentioned by @fvwmer, or my personal favorite, [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/), being an easy scripting language for browsing sites, downloading content and even filling out webforms.

```
import re
import twill

go('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
content = show() #saving content in a variable
if re.search('some regex', content):
       'do something'
```